# Android Studio could not remove dir

Tags: java, android-studio, logcat

When I try to run my application in android studio emulator, I get an error as follows:

```
studio.deploy           install_server-09f4021c              E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
```

So I tried making the directory, but I still get the same issue when i try to run the app.

The app itself loads however the core the functionalities are redundant

Im using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Please some one tell me a fix.

**EDIT:**
So i tried uninstalling and installing the app again in my avd emulator and i get new set of errors:

```
 E  failed to find package com.example.myapplication
2023-04-24 18:49:21.865   557-582   OverlayManager          system_process                       E  Failed to change enabled overlays for com.example.myapplication user 0
2023-04-24 18:49:28.486 14358-14358 studio.deploy           installer                            E  InstallClient: Could not copy '/data/local/tmp/.studio/tmp/09f4021c/install_server' to '/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/install_server-09f4021c: out='', err='run-as: unknown package: com.example.myapplication
                                                                                                    run-as: unknown package: com.example.myapplication
                                                                                                    '
2023-04-24 18:49:28.540 14358-14358 studio.deploy           installer                            E  run-as: unknown package: com.example.myapplication
2023-04-24 18:49:28.706 16338-16338 studio.deploy           sh                                   E  Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.example.myapplication
2023-04-24 18:49:28.751 16338-16338 studio.deploy           sh                                   E  Could not find apks for this package: com.example.myapplication
```

Comment: I'm also getting the same error (the first one), but my app is compiling and not crashing.

Comment: You can terminate the java.exe process from your Task Manager of your operating system and then Rebuild Project in Android Studio